# Can't install apk on Android Things running on a Rasberry Pi 3B

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, android-things

I can install the apk and debug and everything works fine, but then (what seems randomly) it starts giving me the following error when I try to install/debug the app:

```
09/16 07:53:46: Launching app
$ adb push C:\Workspace\new-project-template-master\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/com.wolf.androidthings.autoherb
$ adb shell pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.wolf.androidthings.autoherb"
Error: android.os.ParcelableException: java.io.IOException: Requested internal only, but not enough space

$ adb shell pm uninstall com.wolf.androidthings.autoherb
$ adb shell pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.wolf.androidthings.autoherb"
Error: android.os.ParcelableException: java.io.IOException: Requested internal only, but not enough space


$ adb shell pm uninstall com.wolf.androidthings.autoherb
Unknown failure (at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:674))
Error while Installing APK
```

The only way I can fix this problem at the moment is flashing the Android Things image again, which is not ideal..

Any ideas on why this is happening?

PS. This is when doing a debug install via Android Studio

Comment: how big is your APK? do you package a lot of 3rd party libraries or a lot of resources or native libs?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this on Android Things with Raspberry Pi. As you have noticed, uninstalling the app via adb doesn't work. I connected with the console via serial and noticed that I was out of space on the filesystem. I had some big log files associated with my app (not sure where, somewhere in `/data/...`). I removed those (as in `rm -f ...`) and then my app installed fine.

Comment: In my case it has been folder /data/misc/crash_reporter/crash/ containing several large crashlogs. rm'd them and all was fine.